# how to see pg_stat_statements specific to desired schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

I have multi-tenant postgres DB. I can see details from `pg_stat_statements` table in the public schema with no issues, but as soon as I switch to a different schema - I get no visibility.

#### What could be done?

```sql
prod=> SET search_path=schema_name;
SET
prod=> SELECT substring(query, 1, 130) AS query,
      calls,
      round(total_exec_time::numeric, 2) AS total_time,
      round(mean_exec_time::numeric, 2) AS mean_time,
      round((100 * total_exec_time / sum(total_exec_time) OVER ())::numeric, 2) AS percentage
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY mean_exec_time DESC
LIMIT 10;
ERROR:  relation "pg_stat_statements" does not exist
LINE 6: FROM pg_stat_statements
             ^
prod=> create extension pg_stat_statements;
ERROR:  extension "pg_stat_statements" already exists

prod=>
```

Comment: `select .. from public.pg_stat_statements`

Comment: There is only one pg_stat_statements, not one per schema.